# can not decoed using utf-8 after encoding with utf-8

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, decode

In a situation I had to store data as `utf-8` and now when I want to fetch and `decode('utf-8')` data it's just simply does not work. Consider line below as an example:

```
\x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87
```

You can simply copy the line below to convert the string above to the human readable format:

```
b"\x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87".decode("utf-8")
```

However could not find a way to convert the string to `bytestring` without corrupting the string. I tried following methods but all of them failed:

```
.decode("utf-8")
.decode()
.bytes()
```

Up until this point I could not find solution in OS or other places. Appreciate any help.

Comment: `print("\x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87".encode("latin1").decode())` returns ˙ساقی‌نامه˙ (I don't understand this, sorry).

Comment: @JosefZ this is the right answer. But I can't understand why ```latin1``` , I mean the string you've decoded is ```farsi/persian``` why ```latin1```? And could you also tell me how did you find out that ```latin1``` is the right encoding ? Please put this as an answer so I can accept this as answer. Thanks, you saved 30.000 records of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87
b'x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87'
```

The above lines (both given in the question) are particular instances of [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=string%20literal#literals) (respectively):

> `\xhh` Character with hex value `hh` (<sup>2, 3</sup>)
>
> ---
>
> <sup>2</sup> Unlike in Standard C, *exactly two hex digits are
> required*.
>
> <sup>3</sup> In a bytes literal, hexadecimal and octal escapes denote
> the byte with the given value. **In a string literal, these escapes
> denote a Unicode character with the given value**.
>
> ---

Let's check the string defined in such a way (inside Python prompt):

```
>>> xstr = "\x0d\x0a\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa7\xd9\x82\xdb\x8c\xe2\x80\x8c\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd9\x85\xd9\x87"
>>> xstr
'\r\nØ³Ø§Ù\x82Û\x8câ\x80\x8cÙ\x86Ø§Ù\x85Ù\x87'
>>> print( xstr)

Ø³Ø§ÙÛâÙØ§Ù
Ù
>>>
```

Apparently, the `print( xstr)` output does not resemble a word in any known language however all its characters belong (by definition) to Unicode range `r'[\u0000-\u00ff]'` i.e. the first 256 of characters in Unicode, and voila - it's [iso-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) aka ['latin1'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

We need to get an encoded version of the `xstr` string as a bytes object, e.g. using [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method or built-in [`bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=built#func-bytes) function. Then

```
print( bytes(xstr,'latin1').decode()); print(xstr.encode("latin1").decode())
```

> ```
> ساقی‌نامه
>
> ساقی‌نامه
> ```

Comment: @JsefZ thank you for the comprehensible description. There is a problem this solution works fine on local but on server still I get ```utf-8``` in terminal. What could go wrong ?

Comment: finally find the way ```print(xstr.encode("latin1").decode('latin1'))``` I don't know why do I have to do ```decode``` with ```latin1``` too.

Comment: @iliya You were a bit short about the string origin in your OQ. Please ask another question with more elaborated [mcve].

Comment: yeah sure . Thanks anyway.